# Give examples of such a non-empty transitive and non-transitive relations $r$ in the set $\mathbb N$

Tags: relations

Provide an example of a non-empty transitive relation $r$ on the set $\mathbb N$ such that the relation $r^{\exists}$ defined in the set $\mathcal{P}$($\mathbb N$) by the condition:
$$\langle X, Y \rangle \in r^{\exists} \iff \exists x \exists y (x \in X \; \wedge \; y \in Y \; \wedge \langle x, y\rangle \in r)$$
(a) is transitive; (b) is not transitive.

---

I started with definition of *transitive* relation. As I understand, $r^{\exists}$ should have 2 conditions: it should be transitive and have condition above (am I right?). But I don't understand how to connect $r$ with $r^{\exists}$?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `*text*` to produce italics, not MathJax.

Comment: Have you tried some examples (forget about "transitive" and "non-transitive", just some examples...)? For instance, if $r$ is the relation $x\leq y$, what is $r^{\exists}$?

Comment: PS Something is missing. You have "so that the relation $r^{\exists}$...." but you don't say *what* is supposed to happen to the relation $r^{\exists}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Relation $r^{\exists}$ is just determined by condition. There is no anything about this "what".

Comment: That is terrible phrasing, then. If I say "Find examples of $r$ so that $r^{\exists}$..." then I expect some property that $r^{\exists}$ is expected to have. If all you have is "given an example of a transitive and a nontransitive relation and then compute the corresponding $r^{\exists}$", then whoever wrote the instructions needs to edit them. If that is the case, then your understanding is incorrect: the property of being transitive and nonstransitive is what $r$ must satisfy, not what $r^{\exists}$ must satisfy. What you have above is not  "condition" on $r^{\exists}$, it's a *definition*.

Comment: OK. So I should find $r$ that is transitive and prove that exists at least one $r^{\exists}$ determined by condition?

Comment: That's nonsensical. Given a relation $r$ on $\mathbb{N}$, $r^{\exists}$ necessarily exists, defined by the condition you give. The instructions appear to be to take a nonempty transitive relation $r$, and describe the corresponding $r^{\exists}$; and to then take a non-transitive relation $r$, and describe *its* corresponding $r^{\exists}$. This is a very badly phrased and as far as I can tell rather dumb problem. That is why I think what you have quoted is either misquoted or not what was intended.

Comment: I have translated it from another language and maybe because of that it sounds a bit weird. But in this "another language" it sounds even worse imo. I will try to retranslate this and add in question.

Comment: What language? Many people here are multilingual. Post the original *in addition* to your translation.

Comment: I have added translation as it should be. And also I think should we move this discussion to chat? P. S Original language is polish

Comment: See, you did have a condition that needed to apply to $r^{\exists}$. This phrasing actually  makes sense. So your task is: start with a transitive relation $r$ that is not empty. That relation will completely and fully determine the relation $r^{\exists}$. That relation, $r^{\exists}$ may be transitive or not transitive. You want to find an example where $r^{\exists}$ is transitive, and an example where $r^{\exists}$ is not transitive.  You should start by doing some examples starting with an $r$ you know and figuring out what $r^{\exists}$ will be then, to get a feel for it.